# amChart Maps | Recognize tap behavior on mobile

Tags: javascript, amcharts

When you hover on the provences on the map below, you'll see the name of the provence. How to imitate this behavior with amCharts on mobile? It would be nice if the label appears on mobile when you tap once. Only one label can be visible at the same time.

I've been looking endlessly to find the answer. I couldn't find the answer in the docs either, for example at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/touch/

Eventually I would like to be able to link to another page when you tap the same province again. So if you tab a provence, and if a label is visible in that provence, then you'll go to another page. The biggest provence on the left (xinjiang) already links to google.com. But I haven't even got a clue on how to listen for the first tap event.

Does anybody, maybe someone with a bit AmCharts experience, have an idea on how to solve this problem?

```js
var chart = am4core.create("mapchina", am4maps.MapChart);
chart.geodata = am4geodata_chinaHigh;
chart.seriesContainer.draggable = false;
chart.seriesContainer.resizable = false;
chart.maxZoomLevel = 1;
chart.chartContainer.wheelable = false;

var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.calculateVisualCenter = true;
polygonSeries.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
polygonSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#30302F");
polygonSeries.tooltip.background.stroke = am4core.color("#30302F");
polygonSeries.tooltip.fontSize = 14;
polygonSeries.tooltip.fontFamily = "Open sans";
polygonSeries.data = [
    {
        id: "CN-XJ",
        name: "Xinjiang",
        url: "www.google.com",
        urlTarget: "_blank"
    },
    {
        id: "CN-NM",
        name: "Neimenggu"
    },
    {
        id: "CN-GX",
        name: "Guangxi"
    },
    {
        id: "CN-NX",
        name: "Ningxia"
    }
];

var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#F26964");
polygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
polygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 1;
polygonTemplate.hoverOnFocus = true;
polygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "[text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 600; font-size: 14px]{name}";
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.urlTarget = "urlTarget";

polygonTemplate.events.on("over", function(event) {
    event.target.zIndex = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    event.target.toFront();
});

var hoverState = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FFD464");
hoverState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#FFD464");
hoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 1;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#mapchina {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/chinaHigh.js"></script>

<div id="mapchina"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover state of each province can be toggled by setting `event.target.isHover` to `true`/`false` (this works best when `polygonTemplate.hoverOnFocus` is set to `false`). The `over` event is triggered for each tap, so the hover state can be enabled there (staying that way until the user interacts again). Checking `event.touch` allows the behaviour of mouse events on non-touch screens to be unaffected.

The tricky part is that the corresponding `out` event does not seem to trigger for touch events. Without this, it's difficult to know whether a tap is the first or second tap on a given province. To work around this, a `document.ontouchend` event can be used instead. In this function, check to see if the `target` is the last province tapped, so that it can behave as an `out` event (this is better, as it will even trigger for a tap outside the chart).

By keeping track of the last tapped province (`tapProvince`), this can be compared in subsequent `over` events to check for an initial or repeat tap. Finally, by setting `event.target.url` to an empty string or the intended URL, it is possible to control navigation.

```js
var chart = am4core.create("mapchina", am4maps.MapChart);
chart.geodata = am4geodata_chinaHigh;
chart.seriesContainer.draggable = false;
chart.seriesContainer.resizable = false;
chart.maxZoomLevel = 1;
chart.chartContainer.wheelable = false;

var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.calculateVisualCenter = true;
polygonSeries.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
polygonSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#30302F");
polygonSeries.tooltip.background.stroke = am4core.color("#30302F");
polygonSeries.tooltip.fontSize = 14;
polygonSeries.tooltip.fontFamily = "Open sans";
polygonSeries.data = [{
    id: "CN-XJ",
    name: "Xinjiang",
    url: "www.google.com",
    urlTarget: "_blank"
  },
  {
    id: "CN-NM",
    name: "Neimenggu"
  },
  {
    id: "CN-GX",
    name: "Guangxi"
  },
  {
    id: "CN-NX",
    name: "Ningxia"
  }
];

var tapProvince;
var tapURL;

var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#F26964");
polygonTemplate.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
polygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 1;
polygonTemplate.hoverOnFocus = false;
polygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "[text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 600; font-size: 14px]{name}";
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.urlTarget = "urlTarget";

polygonSeries.calculateVisualCenter = true;
polygonTemplate.tooltipPosition = "fixed";

document.ontouchend = function(event) {
  if (tapProvince && !tapProvince.dom.contains(event.target)) {
    tapProvince.isHover = false;
    tapProvince.url = tapURL;
    tapProvince = undefined;
  };
};

polygonTemplate.events.on("over", function(event) {
  event.target.zIndex = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  event.target.toFront();

  if (event.touch) {
    event.target.isHover = true;

    if (tapProvince && tapProvince.dom === event.target.dom) {
      //after first tap
      event.target.url = tapURL;
    } else {
      //first tap
      tapProvince = event.target;
      tapURL = event.target.url;
      event.target.url = "";
    };
  };
});

var hoverState = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FFD464");
hoverState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#FFD464");
hoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 1;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#mapchina {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/chinaHigh.js"></script>

<div id="mapchina"></div>
```

Comment: That is really impressive and a very cool result! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! It was more challenging than expected, but ended up being an interesting problem to solve. I'm glad it worked for you :)